# Issue on save aif file format in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

I tried to write the file format of "output.aif". I used the below code to write it to a path. The file got saved in two locations one at the path I specified and one more it got saved in the image gallery by default and the name of the file is of a random number. While exiting the application I use to delete the saved ".aif" files from the location I saved, But I couldnt delete the files that got saved in the gallery as I dont know the name of the files.

Is there any way to stop saving the "aif" files from gallery which is happening default.

Can any one suggest a different code to save the file in a location, which wont save the file in gallery?

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];



[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
    if (error) {
    }
    else{            
        NSString *outputTp = [[[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/"] stringByAppendingString:@"output.aif"] retain];
        inUrl = [url retain];
        outUrl = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputSound] retain];
        reader = [[EAFRead alloc] init];
        writer = [[EAFWrite alloc] init];
        self.url = outputTp;


        // this thread does the processing
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(processThread:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    }
}];
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you save into library? Where does come from output.aif at first? It's yours? Well, there are plenty tutorial about saving data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. this is happening because you use `writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:`. are you asking for how to download a video at a given URL to your documents directory?